# htaccess redirect only if no parameters are provided

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website like `www.website.com/index.php` which is the homepage.
I select the different product with several parameters, example `www.website.com/index.php?id=xxx` or `www.website.com/index.php?cat=xxxx`

I have several lines in my htaccess to redirect the query. For example, for the products I use the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^product/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

that works fine.

Now I would like to redirect to the domain root the requests to index.php that do not have any parameters, so `www.website.com/index.php` should become `www.website.com`. Any other query should not be affected. How can I do it ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` to test that the query string is empty, followed by `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=302]` should probably do the job. (Make it 301, when you confirmed that everything works as expected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# test that the query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301]
```

That should do the job.